# How send Firebase Push notification in django

Tags: django, firebase, push-notification, django-rest-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed the steps.

- `pip install fcm-django`

Edit your settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ("fcm_django")

FCM_DJANGO_SETTINGS = {
        "FCM_SERVER_KEY": "[your api key]"
}
```

and then

- manage.py migrate

How do I send push messages on tokens ?? I didn't understand the following method

```
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice
device = FCMDevice.objects.all().first()
device.send_message("Title", "Message")
device.send_message(data={"test": "test"})
device.send_message(title="Title", body="Message", icon=..., data={"test": "test"})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pip install pyfcm

OR

pip install git+https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM.git

```
# Send to single device.
from pyfcm import FCMNotification

push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="<api-key>")

registration_id = "<device registration_id>"
message_title = "Uber update"
message_body = "Hi john, your customized news for today is ready"
result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
print result
```

OR

```
# Send to multiple devices by passing a list of ids.
registration_ids = ["<device registration_id 1>", "<device registration_id 2>", ...]
message_title = "Uber update"
message_body = "Hope you're having fun this weekend, don't forget to check today's news"
result = push_service.notify_multiple_devices(registration_ids=registration_ids, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)

print result
```

after google myself getting this result and its working for more info use this link https://pypi.org/project/pyfcm/0.0.4/

Comment: Getting error : type object 'Retry' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_ALLOWED_METHODS' using python 3.8 version. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

They are the methods to send msg or notification. you have to call these methods in your views whenever you have to send msg.

you can create a common method

```
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice
def send_notification(user_id, title, message, data):
    try:
        device = FCMDevice.objects.filter(user=user_id).last()
        result = device.send_message(title=title, body=message, data=data, 
           sound=True)
        return result
    except:
        pass
```

and add call this method whenever you have to send msg or notification.

```
send_notification(user_id=1, title="Order Return", message="your
    message", data=None)
```